# Mp4Parser for Android

Tags: android, parsing, mp4, mp4parser

I am trying to parse a video using mp4Parser. Now the [online code](https://mp4parser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/ShortenExample.java) works fine

But When I try to run it for android, it gives an Error. The problem seems to be with

`Movie movie = MovieCreator.build(new FileInputStream("/home/sannies/CSI.S13E02.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4").getChannel());`

Which throws an uncaught exception that forces the program to stop working. Can anyone kindly tell me if I have to make any modifications to the code to make it work on android device.

Comment: Post your code and exception

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
File folderPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/abc"".mp4");.
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);.  
MovieCreator.build(Channels.newChannel(file));.
```